# Splitting a single linked list in half

Tags: c++, merge, split, linked-list, traversal

I'm having a bit of trouble with my data structures assignment and would really appreciate some help. I'm creating a linked list from an input file, the file contains an even number of first names. I'm supposed to make five functions; readFile, splitMerge, merge, and traverse. I've done readFile already but I can't figure out how to split the list.

**SplitMerge function**: Create a split function that divides the newly created linked list into two equal sublists: myList1 and myList2. For example, originally you would point to (John, Jack, Jill, Jim). After the split, myList1 would point to john and jack and myList2 would point to jill and Jim.

My code so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string data;
    Node *next;
};

typedef Node *NodePtr;

NodePtr &readFile(NodePtr &, string); //function inputs the list

    void printList(NodePtr &); // function to print it out
    void splitMerge(NodePtr &, NodePtr &, string);
    void merge(); //ignore this
    void traverse(); //ignore this

int main() {
    ifstream fileIn("input.txt");

    string data;
    NodePtr head = NULL;
    NodePtr list2 = new Node();

        while (fileIn >> data)
        {
        readFile(head, data);   
        }
        cout << "Singly linked list: " << endl;
            printList(head);    
            cout << endl;

        splitMerge(head, list2, data);
        cout << "Split list: " << endl;
            printList(list2);

    fileIn.close();
return 0;
}

NodePtr &readFile(NodePtr &head,string data)
{
    NodePtr Alpha = new Node(); //new node called "Alpha
    Alpha->data = data; //assign alpha data to passed in "data"
    Alpha->next = NULL;
    NodePtr p = head; //head node

        if (p == NULL) head = Alpha; //if p is null, head is assigned alpha.
        else
        {
            while (p->next != NULL) p = p->next; //Fill nodes
            p->next = Alpha;
        }
    return head;
}

void printList(NodePtr &head)
{
    NodePtr p = head;

        while (p != NULL) //step through nodes till reaches NULL (end).
        {
            cout << p->data;
            p = p->next;
            cout << endl;
        }
}

void splitMerge(NodePtr &head, NodePtr &list2, string data)
{
    //NodePtr p = head;
    NodePtr slow = head;
    NodePtr fast = head;
    //list2->next = NULL;


    if (head != NULL)
    {
        while (fast != NULL && fast->next != NULL)
        {
            fast = fast->next->next;
            slow = slow->next;
        }
        list2->data = slow->data;
    }

    //while (list2->next != NULL) list2 = list2->next; //Fill nodes
    //list2->next = list2;
}
```

Names in text file:

```
Sean
Megan
John
Alex
Ginger
Sam
Sarah
Jack
```

**Edit: Okay so I think I got the split. It now compiles, runs, and correctly splits the list in two. The only issue I'm having now is my second list only has one name in it, Ginger. How do I include nodes 4-8 in list2? A bit lost here.**

Comment: I don't see your attempt.

Comment: Well I don't really know where to start, I've spent the last 6 or so hours working on what you see there. All the info I can find about splitting linked lists is about circular or double lists.

Comment: I understand, but nobody here is going to do the work for you. When programming, you can't expect to find the solutions to problems by looking for answers. You have to think about them, break them down into smaller problems, solve each piece, put the pieces together, and then debug when it doesn't work. Try to be more specific about what you're not understanding.

Comment: Loop over the elements of original list. Store `next` pointer of middle element as pointer to first element of list 2. Set `next` pointer of middle element to `nullptr` to make the split. That's it.

Comment: @zett42 Okay, that was sort of what I started. A for loop with a counter that stops when reaching null. how do I get the midpoint though, count/2 = midpoint?

Comment: `p / i` can't work. After counting number of elements, you have to loop again to get to the midpoint, which is `count / 2`.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I came up with something a bit different. (Check Edits on main post). What do you think of that? @zett42

Comment: @Solus - re: edits. Does it compile? Does it run?

Comment: Builds but wont run. I don't think I'm calling it right in main.

Comment: Edit may have issue with uneven number of list elements, I'm too tired to think it through.

Comment: Yeah it's ok if it can't handle odd numbered lists. Professor told us to just put an even number of names on the input.txt file (i have 8)

Comment: I don't see a reason for `list2->data = slow->data` .

Comment: I'm assigning slow to the beginning of list2. Right now it's working but it only shows the one name, Ginger, which is correct, it's in the middle, but how can I get it show the other 3 names in list2. (check edits) thanks! @rcgldr

Answer (score 0):

Fixes noted in comments. I didn't use stdafx.h, as I use an "emtpy" project. I changed mergesplit() to only use two parameters.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string data;
    Node *next;
};

typedef Node *NodePtr;

NodePtr &readFile(NodePtr &, string); //function inputs the list
void printList(NodePtr &); // function to print it out
void splitMerge(NodePtr &, NodePtr &);          // fix
void merge(); //ignore this
void traverse(); //ignore this

int main() {
    ifstream fileIn("input.txt");

    string data;
    NodePtr head = NULL;
    NodePtr list2 = NULL;                       // fix

    while (fileIn >> data)
        readFile(head, data);                   // simplify
    cout << "Singly linked list: " << endl;
    printList(head);    
    cout << endl;

    splitMerge(head, list2);
    cout << "First list:" << endl;              // show both lists
    printList(head);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Second list:" << endl;
    printList(list2);

    fileIn.close();
    return 0;
}

NodePtr &readFile(NodePtr &head,string data)
{
    NodePtr Alpha = new Node(); //new node called "Alpha
    Alpha->data = data; //assign alpha data to passed in "data"
    Alpha->next = NULL;
    NodePtr p = head; //head node

        if (p == NULL) head = Alpha; //if p is null, head is assigned alpha.
        else
        {
            while (p->next != NULL) p = p->next; //Fill nodes
            p->next = Alpha;
        }
    return head;
}

void printList(NodePtr &head)
{
    NodePtr p = head;

        while (p != NULL) //step through nodes till reaches NULL (end).
        {
            cout << p->data;
            p = p->next;
            cout << endl;
        }
}

void splitMerge(NodePtr &head, NodePtr &list2)  // fix
{
    NodePtr slow = head;
    NodePtr fast = head;
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)      // simplify
        return;                                 // simplify

    while (fast->next->next != NULL)            // fix
    {
        fast = fast->next->next;
        slow = slow->next;
    }
    list2 = slow->next;                         // fix
    slow->next = NULL;                          // fix
}
```

Although beyond the class assignment, a bottom up merge sort for lists would be faster for large lists. Wiki has a pseudo code example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Then again, it's faster still to copy the list into an array, delete the list, sort the array (std::sort or std::stable_sort would work), then copy the array to a new list, delete the array. If the nodes are large enough, it may be faster to create an array of pointers to nodes, and sort the array of pointers, then create a new list from the pointers.